# CSS Transition effects missing after uploading to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, azure

I don't know how to ask this but here is what's happening.

I got my website ready with the CSS transition, style and stuffs.
But when i uploaded to azure, certain CSS styles and transitions suddenly stopped working.

Such as:

> 1) My website have a sticker header/navbar that only appears after scrolling till a certain page but after uploading, it appeared in the first page.
>
> 2) My menu have a smooth dropdown effect but it became instant dropdown in azure
>
> 3) when clicking the menu which will smoothly scroll to the right page, it became instant without the transition.

PS. My website have styles similar to http://www.wampserver.com/en/ where everything is in a single page.

I really don't know where to start looking!
I tried deleting the contents of the website and reuploading but it's the same thing.

Could my website be not compatible with azure?

The codes i use is simple CSS codes:

```
 -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 transition: height 0.35s ease;
```

Comment: Check and verify your script paths ?

Comment: everything is in the right place, the CSS came out properly, just the transitions are messed up

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is going wrong with your website, but normally the output of css files is unparsed and only interpreted by your web-browser.

I cannot give you a solution, but i can give you some debug advices:

- Is everything okay with your HTML Markup? Is it generated dynamically? Maybe it is malformed?
- Are you really sure, that azure outputs the newest version of your css file? Not an older or cached one? Are you using dynamic generated ID's as style-selectors?
- Do you use JavaScript? Are there any scripting errors?

You could use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or any other browser's web-development tool to validate your markup, css and JavaScript.

If this wont help you, you could use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to inspect and debug traffic and compare the working output from local-enviroment with the output from your azure-enviroment. Can you find any differences?